# Calculate Earth angular speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, earth, speed, angular-velocity

How may I calculate Earth's angular speed at specific point (The green dot for example)?

**Note:** I know that angular speed $= \dfrac{2\pi}{T}$ But how may I found $T$ in this case?

I found too that $R_{\text{new}}=R_{\text{old}}\sin (43)$ where $R_{old}$ stands for *radius of Earth*

[image]

Comment: How about T = 24 hours?

Comment: That's not true... I do exist in different location which means at the green point it will finish rotating faster

Comment: How long is a day where you live?

Comment: Where ever you are, a say (day + night) is ALWAYS 24 h.

Comment: A [sidereal day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time) is approximately 23 hours, 56 minutes, 4.0905 seconds = 23.9344696 h.

Answer (score 2):

> How may I calculate earth's angular speed at specific point (The green
> dot for example)?

The *angular velocity* doesn't depend on the position of the green dot. Assuming uniform rotational speed it is simply:

$$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$$

where $T$ is the *period of rotation*, in the case of Earth $T=24\mathrm{h}$.

The *tangential velocity* $v$ for a point is given by:

$$v=R\omega$$

where $R$ is the distance of the point to the axis of rotation (in your case $R_{earth}\sin\lambda$).

Comment: I'm trying to solve a question on how much coriolis force will affect a ball falling from a height of 150m from the green point, so what you are saying is that the result is not related to the position which is wrong.

Comment: But you don't even mention Coriolis in your question!!!

Comment: because you said specific questions are forbidden

Comment: **because you said specific questions are forbidden** where did I say that???

Comment: @Daniel98 Gert’s answer is correct. It does not imply that the Coriolis force is independent of position. You jumped to an erroneous conclusion.

Comment: Maybe you should raise another question about Coriolis? Trust me, it's allowed! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Notice, the angular speed $\omega$ of each and every on a rotating body remains constant irrespective of its position from the axis of rotation.

The angular speed at any point of a rotating body having period of one revolution $T$ (i.e. $24$ hrs for the Earth) is given as follows
$$\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}\ \ (\text{rad/s})$$
If $r$ is the normal distance of any specific point from the axis of rotation then its tangential velocity $v$ is given as
$$v=r\omega \ \ (\text{m/s})$$

[image]

The normal distance of green dot from the axis of rotation is $R_{old}\sin\lambda$. Where $\lambda=43^\circ$. The angular speed $\omega$ of green dot will be constant while its tangential velocity $v$ will be
$$v=(R_{old}\sin43^\circ)\omega$$

Comment: This answer seems to simply repeat Gert’s answer.